# Numerical month to character month in excel

Tags: excel

Is there a pre-installed function that directly converts 08 to Aug, 10 to Oct?

Currently I use `text(date(0,have,1),"mmm")`.

Comment: What does `have` point to? Have you tried replacing `have` with a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify like this:  `=TEXT("8/0","mmm")`.

**Update**

I've come up with a new technique:  =TEXT(*number* * 30,"mmm"):

[image]

**How it works**

Dates are stored as numbers in Excel.  The number 1 is the date Jan 1, 1900; 2 is Jan 2, 1900; etc.

The 30th day in 1900 is in January; the 60th day is in February; the 90th day is in March.

Every multiple of 30 between 30 and 360 is in a different month.  So we can simply multiply 30 by a number between 1 and 12, and the `TEXT` function will give us the month.

Comment: Seems it doesn't work. If cell A1 contains `08`, then your formula is `=text(A1/0,"mmm")` ?

Comment: "/0" must be in quotes.  Otherwise, you're dividing be zero.  So it would need to be `=text(A1&"/0","mmm")`.

Comment: I've added a new method, which is easier.  But to answer your question: There's no built-in worksheet formula besides `TEXT` that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
MonthName(yourmonthNumber)
```

or

```
MonthName(yourmonthNumber, True) 'to abbreviate the name
```

Or did you mean a worksheet function?